# How can I allow All users can login() while they are inactive in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

my views :

```
code = random.randint(100000, 999999)
def register(request):
 #### when registration is ok
            global code
            subject = 'ok'
            message = "activation code" + str(code)
            email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            send_mail(subject, message, email_from, [email])
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            login(request, user)           ### problem is here, user cant login because activation is false
            return redirect('email_activation/')


def email_activation(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        global code
        email_activation = request.POST['email_activation']
        if str(email_activation) == str(code):
            request.user.is_active = True
            request.user.save()
            return redirect('account')
```

auth.backends.py :

```
def user_can_authenticate(self, user):
    """
    Reject users with is_active=False. Custom user models that don't have
    that attribute are allowed.
    """
    is_active = getattr(user, 'is_active', None)
    return is_active or is_active is None
```

user should login in register to can activation become True in email activation
i would be glad someone help me to how inactive user can login

Comment: Please *don't* use global variables: it makes servers less predictable, unscalable, and results in all sorts of bugs that are hard to fix. Use the database to store an activation code in.

Comment: can I have email activation inside register def for example make `if request.method == "POST":` after ` user.is_active = False  user.save()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override django `ModelBackend`'S `user_can_authenticate()` method.

the class is located here :  `'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'`

just return there `True`

and then update your settings.py file authentication backend with you new inherited `ModelBackend` which is overridden the method `user_can_authenticate`

Here you go for more details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend.user_can_authenticate

If you want to authenticate directly as an inactive user, you can use django built-in `authenticate` method. and pass the method appropriate data

Comment: I have backends.py in my app so should i add  `class AuthenticationFormWithInactiveUsersOkay(AuthenticationForm):
    def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):
        pass`

Comment: You have to override this class: ` 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'` there is a method named `user_can_authenticate`

Comment: can you tell me where should i use `user_can_authenticate` i little confused now

Comment: check the answer now

Comment: i found this :         """
        `Reject users with is_active=False. Custom user models that don't have
        that attribute are allowed.
        """
        is_active = getattr(user, 'is_active', None)
        return is_active or is_active is None`

Comment: i add it in main question please check it

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this git commit https://github.com/django/django/commit/a1889397a9f0e6a35189de455098b4c70923e561.

I've made all users to login, regardless of the "is_active" status by overriding the `confirm_login_allowed` method for custom login form inherited from `AuthenticationForm`

```
class AuthenticationFormWithInactiveUsersOkay(AuthenticationForm):     
    def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):         
        pass
```

Besides, use the `AllowAllUsersModelBackend` backend by adding one more line in settings.py:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ["django.contrib.auth.backends.AllowAllUsersModelBackend"]
```

These two changes work well for me. If the previous `confirm_login_allowed` method is not overridden, the login form will show user inactive error message when inactive users want to login. Otherwise, you may also want to override the `clean` method for your login form, but I would not recommend so, because Django's `clean` method in `AuthenticationForm` should handle well.